# Decorator, dependency injection and pylance typing

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I'm trying to move instantiating of sqlalchemy session to decorator, because I have dozens of functions which make a lot of queries and rely on AsyncSession object.
Code works fine.

- Database.session() is decorated with @asynccontextmanager and returns AsyncSession object.

But can I avoid checking "if not session"?

- If I make argument strict "session: AsyncSession", then Pylance shows me error on "await create_model()", because I don't pass argument "session".

Can I make somehow

- async def create_model(session: AsyncSession)
- do not pass "session" to create_model() in main(), and not having Pylance error

```
def with_session(func):
    async def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        async with Database.session() as session:
            await func(*args, **kwargs, session=session)

    return inner


@with_session
async def create_model(session: AsyncSession | None = None):
    if not session:
        raise
    session.add(Model())
    await session.commit()


async def main():
    await create_model()
```

**UPDATE 10.02.2023**

After making some progress with Chepner's solution, I realized that call "await create_model()" sometimes have to have argument "session" (and often some other arguments).
So, I decided to make new version with using of protocols.

```
T = TypeVar('T', covariant=True)
P = ParamSpec('P')


class SomeType(Protocol[T, P]):
    async def __call__(self, session: AsyncSession, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        ...


class SomeTypePossible(Protocol[T, P]):
    async def __call__(self, session: AsyncSession | None = None, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> Awaitable[T]:
        ...


def with_session(func: SomeType[T, P]) -> SomeTypePossible[T, P]:
    async def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
        if 'session' in kwargs and (s := kwargs.pop('session')) and isinstance(s, AsyncSession):
            return await func(s, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            async with Database.session() as session:
                return await func(session=session, *args, **kwargs)

    return inner


@with_session
async def create_model(session: AsyncSession, a: str | None = None) -> str:
    await session.commit()
    return 'test'


async def main():
    async with Database.session() as s:
        p = await create_model(session=s, a='other_test')
        print(p)
```

Almost everything is ok, except Pylance warning about "return inner":

```
Expression of type "(*args: P@with_session.args, **kwargs: P@with_session.kwargs) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, T@with_session]" cannot be assigned to return type "SomeTypePossible[T@with_session, P@with_session]"
  Type "(*args: P@with_session.args, **kwargs: P@with_session.kwargs) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, T@with_session]" cannot be assigned to type "(session: AsyncSession | None = None, **P@with_session) -> Coroutine[Any, Any, Awaitable[T@with_session]]"
    Function return type "Coroutine[Any, Any, T@with_session]" is incompatible with type "Coroutine[Any, Any, Awaitable[T@with_session]]"
      "Coroutine[Any, Any, T@with_session]" is incompatible with "Coroutine[Any, Any, Awaitable[T@with_session]]"
        Type parameter "_ReturnT_co@Coroutine" is covariant, but "T@with_session" is not a subtype of "Awaitable[T@with_session]"
          "object*" is incompatible with protocol "Awaitable[T@with_session]"Pylance
```

I'm not quite sure what is happening in that situation. May I ask anybody to explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide `with_session` with type hints that will let the type checker know that the type of `create_model` et al. is changed by the decorator.

```
from typing import Awaitable, Callable, Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar


P = ParamSpec('P')
RV = TypeVar('RV')


def with_session(func: Callable[Concatenate[AsyncSession, P], Awaitable[RV]]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[None]]:
    async def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> None:
        async with Database.session() as session:
            await func(session, *args, **kwargs)

    return inner


@with_session
def create_model(session: AsyncSession):
    session.add(Model())
    await session.commit()
```

- `Callable[Concatenate[AsyncSession, P], Awaitable[RV]]`

  The type of `func` indicates an arbitrary callable that takes at least an argument of type `AsyncSession`; if there are any other parameters, they are represented by the parameter specification `P`. The return type is an awaitable value that provides some arbitrary type `RV`.
- `Callable[P, Awaitable[None]]`

  The return type of `with_session` is another callable, with the same parameters as `func`, but *without* the parameter of type `AsyncSession` and a hard-coded return value of `None`.

  @with_session
  async def create_model(session: AsyncSession):
  session.add(Model())
  await session.commit()

Now we can define `create_model` as a callable that *must* receive an `AsyncSession`, so there is no need to check if `session` is `None`. The original `create_model` is bound to the name `func` in the closure returned by `with_session`; the new `create_model` is the closure, which only takes parameters captured by `P` (which does *not* include `AsyncSession`).

(I don't use VSCode, so I can't test this with PyLance, but it works with `mypy`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chepner! Solution works great. Tried on VSCode 1.86.0, python 3.10.13 and Pylance v2024.2.1 in strict checking mode.

Answer (score 0):

So my final solution is using protocols.
Works good on VSCode 1.86.0, Python 3.10.13 and Pylance v2024.2.1 in strict checking mode.

```
T = TypeVar('T', covariant=True)
P = ParamSpec('P')


class SomeType(Protocol[T, P]):
    async def __call__(self, session: AsyncSession, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        ...


class SomeTypePossible(Protocol[T, P]):
    async def __call__(self, session: AsyncSession | None = None, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        ...


def with_session(func: SomeType[T, P]) -> SomeTypePossible[T, P]:
    async def inner(session: AsyncSession | None = None, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        if session:
            return await func(session=session, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            async with Database.session() as session:
                return await func(session=session, *args, **kwargs)

    return inner


@with_session
async def create_task(session: AsyncSession, *, task: schemas.Task) -> models.Task:
    model = models.Task(**task.model_dump())
    ...
    return model



async def main():
   task = something()
   #if I need, I can start session here and pass await create_task(session=my_new_session, task=task)
   result = await create_task(task=task)
```